# How to create integration test for a mojo that provides a custom packaging

Tags: maven-3, mojo

I've created a mojo using maven 3.2.2 that provides a custom packaging. This custom package triggers the generation of a custom compacted file.
I would like to create a functional test for it and given a project with a pom to verify if the file was generated.

which tool should I use ? pointing me to a code example would be great !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go via [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) which supports such scenarios. Real examples can be found in many Maven plugins for example

- https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/mojo/tags/appassembler-1.8.1/appassembler-maven-plugin/src/it
- https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it
- https://github.com/khmarbaise/artifactor-maven-plugin/tree/master/src
- https://github.com/khmarbaise/uptodate-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it
- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-assembly-plugin-2.4

Comment: thanks Karl. I was able to create a simple test and a script for my plugin. But it is failing because the configuration pojo is not being injected. do I need to do any setup in order to have a @parameter with an alias injected?